# Backfilling previous dates in R

Tags: r

Let's take a trivial dataframe

```
structure(list(a = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", 
"b"), class = "factor"), dt = structure(c(NA, 17287, 17318, NA, 
17379, 17410), class = "Date")), .Names = c("a", "dt"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

which gives the following

```
  a         dt
1 a       <NA>
2 a 2017-05-01
3 a 2017-06-01
4 b       <NA>
5 b 2017-08-01
6 b 2017-09-01
```

In my actual data, I have this happening multiple times.  How can I backfill with the previous month start date.

Ideally I would like to do this using `dplyr`.  The closest I could get was using `lubridate::floor_date` and `dplyr::lead` that leads to making the last date an `NA`.

```
tmp %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  mutate(dt = floor_date(lead(dt, 1) - 1, "month"))

# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups:   a [2]
  a     dt        
  <fct> <date>    
1 a     2017-04-01
2 a     2017-05-01
3 a     NA        
4 b     2017-07-01
5 b     2017-08-01
6 b     NA
```

Thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Could there be more than 1 missing `dt` in a row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually really close to the answer. You just need the package `lubridate` in addition to `dplyr`:

```
tmp <- structure(list(a = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", "b"), class = "factor"), 
                      dt = structure(c(NA, 17287, 17318, NA, 17379, 17410), class = "Date")),
                 .Names = c("a", "dt"), 
                 row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
                 class = "data.frame")

library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

tmp %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  mutate(newDT = if_else(is.na(dt), lead(dt) %m-% months(1), dt))
tmp

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   a [2]
  a     dt         newDT     
  <fct> <date>     <date>    
1 a     NA         2017-04-01
2 a     2017-05-01 2017-05-01
3 a     2017-06-01 2017-06-01
4 b     NA         2017-07-01
5 b     2017-08-01 2017-08-01
6 b     2017-09-01 2017-09-01
```

I'm not good at working with Excel-style dates in R, but I assume that once you get here you can convert `newDT` into the format you want. (EDIT: thanks to @phiver for correcting my code!)

Comment: use dplyr's `if_else` instead of base R `ifelse` and the dates will look good.

Comment: @phiver ah yes, I forgot about `dplyr::if_else` to maintain the data type.  That solves the problem.  If the answer is updated I will accept.

Comment: The output from the code still needs to be updated but I will accept.

Comment: @cdeterman and mmyoung77, I edited the code / example so it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the currently accepted solution won't work if there are more than 1 adjacent `NA` value for `dt`.

Here's an alternative, note the order is important:

#### solution

```
dat

  a         dt
1 a       <NA>
2 a       <NA>
3 a 2017-05-01
4 a 2017-06-01
5 b       <NA>
6 b 2017-08-01
7 b 2017-09-01

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  mutate(helper = ifelse(is.na(dt), NA, cumsum(!is.na(dt)))) %>%
  fill(helper, .direction = 'up') %>%
  group_by(a, helper) %>%
  mutate(dt = coalesce(dt,
                       max(dt, na.rm = TRUE) - months(max(row_number()) - row_number()))) %>%
  dplyr::select(-helper)

# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   a, helper [4]
  helper a     dt        
   <int> <fct> <date>    
1      1 a     2017-03-01
2      1 a     2017-04-01
3      1 a     2017-05-01
4      2 a     2017-06-01
5      1 b     2017-07-01
6      1 b     2017-08-01
7      2 b     2017-09-01
```

#### data

```
dat <-structure(list(a = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", 
"b"), class = "factor"), dt = structure(c(NA, NA, 17287, 17318, 
NA, 17379, 17410), class = "Date")), .Names = c("a", "dt"), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = "data.frame")
```